# How to prevent IIS Express in visual studio from caching data from SQL server?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am developing an asp.net MVC application in visual studio 2015.
I change data in SQL Server Management studio, and refresh my webpage that get data from SQL server but changes does not apply in web page.
When I close IIS express in system tray and restart my project changes of data will shown.
It seems to IIS express cache data from sql server!
How can I prevent IIS from this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any Answer? 
Ok, i found a way that cause IIS Express to Restart my website and in this way the cached data erased and my problem solved

- in system tray RightClick on IIS Express and select Show All Applications
- in the list of Running Applications click on your site name
- click on link of applicationhost.config file to be opened in notepad(dont change its content!)
  [image]

   and now everytime that data cached you can just resave(Ctrl+S) the config file and reload your webpage.